# Android Toolbar (as widget) not showing title

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I am using `Toolbar` as a widget in the bottom sheet. But the title doesn't show.

[image]

My `Toolbar` content in bottomsheet layout is like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:title="This is my title"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:onClick="@{() -> handler.hideBottomSheet()}"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_down_black_24dp" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    //...

</LinearLayout>
```

Everything looks good. But title doesn't just show up. This is not a support `ActionBar`. I am using this as a widget.

I don't know why, but it just doesn't show. I've tried different themes and also changing background color of the root `LinearLayout`, but no luck.

It just doesn't show up. I've also tried setting `android:titleTextColor` but that also didn't worked.

Can title only used when using as `ActionBar`? Or Am I doing something wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: pz post your java code

Comment: Java code of which part?

Comment: replacing actionbar with toolbar...

Comment: if you do not want to use setActionBar then toolbar is simply a layout, use TextView widget along with relative layout to show text within the toolbar layout.

Comment: So title atteibute will not work?

Comment: I dont think so, you can try the setSuportAction bar and see if it works. Otherwise just treat your toolbar as a widget(a simple layout) and use relative layout to set the text within the toolbar

Comment: Use textview inside Toolbar tag to set title

Comment: I think it should also work using setSupportActionBar, you must be using this toolbar layout in a fragment/Activity only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the documents

> Using XML attributes from the support library
>
> Notice that the showAsAction attribute above uses a custom namespace
>   defined in the tag. This is necessary when using any XML attributes
>   defined by the support library, because these attributes do not exist
>   in the Android framework on older devices. So you must use your own
>   namespace as a prefix for all attributes defined by the support
>   library.

You need to use custom prefix for that. So use `app:title` in place of `android:title` as follows.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    app:title="This is my title"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:onClick="@{() -> handler.hideBottomSheet()}"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_down_black_24dp" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

> Can title only used when using as ActionBar?

It is not necessary. You can get `toolbar name` without setting it as `actionbar`

Comment: @kirtan403 did that help you?

Comment: Sorry,  I just checked! It worked. Thank you so much. I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
mActionBarToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);
mActionBarToolbar.setTitle("");
setSupportActionBar(mActionBarToolbar);
```

now you can set your title

```
mActionBarToolbar.setTitle(title);
```

Comment: I am not using this as actionbar. I am usin in bottomsheet